# How to force wget to download a directory from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, wget

I tried downloading a dropbox directory using the following command.

```
wget -O reads -r "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1eqzxexmei28ihx/AAAnjVNqUl8MJFH51j9PILf-a?dl=1
```

It downloads, but the result is a file not a directory

```
$ ls
-rw-r--r--@ 1 juliofdiaz  staff   5.3M 13 Dec 17:07 reads
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

With the option `-O` you can specify only a single file, so it is not the correct option to download multiple file.

> -O file
>   --output-document=file
>   The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but **all will be concatenated together and written to `file`**.

What you need if you want to specify a directory as a target is `-P`:

> -P prefix
>   --directory-prefix=prefix
>   Set directory prefix to prefix.  The directory prefix is the directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree.

Comment: I used ` wget -P newDir -r "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1eqzxexmei28ihx/AAAnjVNqUl8MJFH51j9PILf-a?dl=1"` and I does download as a directory, but it does not download the contents.

Comment: That is because the link refers to a single file. If you want to download recursively, you need a link to a page that provides links to the files you want to download.

Comment: Any idea how that could be accomplished with a Dropbox dir?

Comment: No, I don't know. You should have some page that lists all your files. Try the URL of that page.